# Is there any advantage to using a wildcard provisioning profile?

Tags: iphone, app-store, provisioning

I remember before reading that if you used a wildcard provisioning id (eg `net.nevan.*`), you could have easier sharing of information between your apps. Now, many things require a provisioning id for each app to be unique (iAds, notifications, in-app purchase). Actually, looking at my apps on the app store, they are all using unique ids.

Is there still an advantage (other than convenience) to using a wildcard id for provisioning profiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest plus is that if you *don't* need unique provisioning profiles, you only need to make one once, and when it expires, you only need to refresh the one provisioning profile.  If you've got 10 applications each with its own development and distribution provisioning profile, that's 20 provisioning profiles you have to keep up with if you're actively developing all 10 applications.  Plus another profile each if you want to do any ad-hoc building for beta testers.